# Could not add env variables when I deploy nextjs app onto fly.io

Tags: fly

I am trying to deploy nextjs app on fly.io. I could not add env variables on docker file & fly.toml.

```
[env]
  API = "https://api-url"
```

I tried to add like that in fly.toml.

API URL is undefined

hope someone can share experiences and help me out if you have.

May I closed my questions, that is not about env variables problems. it is happen bc of nextjs staticsideprops is not working. I changed serversideprops, it can work now.

that can help me https://community.fly.io/t/secrets-undefined-build-error-next-js-app/9709/2